# Regex to NOT match a string with 10 consecutive digits. The digits may be separated by white space. All other string return a match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a codepen with 5/7 unit tests passing. Stuck on strings starting with non-digit characters.

https://codepen.io/david-grieve/pen/pBpGoO?editors=0012

```
var regexString = /^\D*(?!(\s*\d\s*){10,}).*/;
```

```js
var regexString = /^\D*(?!(\s*\d\s*){10,}).*/;

var tests = [{
    text: 'abc123',
    ismatch: true
  }, {
    text: '1234567890',
    ismatch: false
  }, {
    text: '123456789',
    ismatch: true
  }, {
    text: 'abc1234567890efg',
    ismatch: false
  }, {
    text: '123 456 789 123',
    ismatch: false
  },
  {
    text: 'abc1234567890',
    ismatch: false
  }, {
    text: '1234567890efg',
    ismatch: false
  }
];

console.log(new Date().toString());
tests.map(test => console.log(test.text, regexString.test(test.text) == test.ismatch));
```

With this regex the following strings pass the unit tests

- "abc123" true
- "1234567890" true
- "123456789" true
- "123 456 789 123" true
- "1234567890efg" true

These fail the unit tests

- "abc1234567890" false
- "abc1234567890efg" false

Note: /^\D{3,}(?!(\s*\d\s*){10,}).*/ passes all the tests but is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Emma He wants every line in the log to show `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `^\D*(?!` is that, even if a long digit/space string is found in the negative lookahead, the part matched by `\D` will simply *backtrack* one character once the negative lookahead matches. Eg, when

```
^\D*(?!\d{10,}).*
```

matches

```
abc1234567890
```

the `\D*` matches `ab`, and the `.*` matches `c1234567890`. The position between the `b` and the `c` is not *immediately* followed by a long number/space substring, so the match does not fail.

Also, because some digits may come *before* the 10 consecutive digits, the `^\D*` at the beginning won't be enough - for example, what if the input is `1a01234567890`? Instead, try

```
^(?!.*(\d\s*){10}).*
```

This ensures that *every* position is not followed by (10 digits, possibly separated by spaces).

https://regex101.com/r/v7t4IC/1

If the digits can only come in a single block (possibly separated by spaces) in the string, your pattern would've worked if you were in an environment which supports *possessive* quantifiers, which prevent backtracking, eg:

```
^\D*+(?!(\s*\d\s*){10,}).*
    ^
```

https://regex101.com/r/eGdw2l/1

(but Javascript does not support such syntax, unfortunately)

Comment: but your regex matches `abc123` ... it shouldn't

Comment: I thought it should? `{ text: 'abc123', ismatch: true}` - he wants it to be a match, because there are no consecutive strings of 10 digits/spaces in it

Comment: oh ...  I thought AT LEAST 10 digits was the criteria based on `{10,}` - I guess that's one of the many things the OP did wrong :p